# Am working in ADF i need to export data from sql source to Excel destination, Is there way to use Excel(.xlsx) as destination in ADF ? Notebook?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, scala, azure-data-factory

Am working in ADF i need to export data from sql source to Excel destination, Is there way to use Excel(.xlsx) as destination in ADF ? Notebook ?

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a guess - use CSV as target and in properties - give .xlsx as file suffix -- it might work but you'll have to download the file from blob storage using Logic App etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Excel isn't supported as sink in ADF. Using Notebook is one way to achieve this. Another way in ADF is creating a Azure Function and then invoke it by [Azure Function activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
Add source as SQL and sink as excel.
This feature was added later to the ADF.

Comment: It would help to specify when this was added — at which date or version?