# Convert SQL table data to Excel file in ADF

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I am creating a workflow in Azure data factory and I wanted to create a excel file with data from the SQL table (Azure SQL server) in any one below scenario:

1. Create excel and upload into blob storage.
2. Create excel and upload into sharepoint.
   But I am unable to find the excel connection in copy activity sink for copying the data into blob. Is there anyway to do that? Please advice.

Comment: Excel is supported as source but not sink. Refer Similar thread in SO (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67189420/am-working-in-adf-i-need-to-export-data-from-sql-source-to-excel-destination-is)

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box feature in ADF to support Excel as a sink.
You would have to use logic app or write your own custom logic via Azure function, Databricks, Azure batch etc to do the above tasks

Answer (score 0):

Write a SQL stored procedure Python in SQL Server Machine learning Services (will only work if SQL Server Machine Learning Services is configured). ADF can then run the stored procedure and place the file into the blob storage. The Blob storage Python libraries are not available on SQL Managed Instance, so the script below uses the Blob REST API's instead.

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script @language = N'Python'
,@input_data_1 = N'SELECT A.* FROM MyTable A'
,@input_data_1_name = N'SQLQueryOutput' 
,@script = N'

import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import requests


# Execute the query to retrieve the data from the SQL Server table
df = SQLQueryOutput

# Write the data to an Excel file
df.to_excel(FileName, index=False)

url = "https://" + AccountName + ".blob.core.windows.net/" + BlobContainerPath + "/" + FileName + "?" + BlobSASToken

payload= open(FileName, "rb")
headers = {
  ''x-ms-blob-type'': ''BlockBlob'',
  ''Content-Type'': ''application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet''
}

response = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)

'
,@params = N'@BlobSASToken VARCHAR(200), @AccountName VARCHAR(100), @BlobContainerPath VARCHAR(200), @FileName VARCHAR(100)'
,@BlobSASToken = N'sp=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&st=xxxxxxxxxxxx&se=xxxxxxxxxxxx&spr=https&sv=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&sr=c&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
,@AccountName = N'myaccountname'
,@BlobContainerPath = N'containername/containerpath'
,@FileName = N'myexcelfilename.xlsx'
```